# Apache 2.4 on Windows 2008 large file downloads are corrupt

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4

I have a 400MB zip file on a server that I am attempting to access directly via a web browser (not through a script). The file seems to download normally, but cuts off at 124 MB as a corrupt file. The same results keep occurring regardless of the browser used.

The Apache access log appear to show a successful download:

```
IP - - [18/Jan/2013:10:07:33 -0500] "GET /url/to/file/myfile.zip HTTP/1/1" 200 455000714
```

There is nothing in the error log.

I've done some searching and the only thing I could find was to add `AcceptFilter http none` which seemingly had no affect.

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Windows 2008 server.

Comment: Are you sure the file is indeed not corrupt on the server?

Comment: Yes.  I can unzip it normally on the server and it works fine when downloaded via SFTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue, and came across this hoping for an answer.
I strongly suspect there is a bug in 2.4 as this didn't happen in 2.2 
After far too much mucking around I finally got my case fixed.
I hope this works for you to I know it's a work around but it's better than nothing.

In my httpd.conf I enabled sendfile.
So swap

```
#EnableSendfile On
```

with

```
EnableSendfile On
```

Comment: i'm using apache 2.4 on win 7 64b with webdav module and got the same issue.
Now solved with "EnableSendfile On".
Thank you

Comment: I am also having an issue of big ZIP files downloaded getting corrupted.
I am using a Docker image from : FROM httpd:2.4.29-alpine. The docker image is serving files mounted from a windows directory. And they were coming corrupted al the time until I enabled the EnabledSenfFile On as said above.  Also believe there mus be a very important bug - either in the intergation with docker windows - or somewhere else. For small tiny files nothing was na issue.

Comment: @Chip Looks like it doesn't happen in 2.2 because EnableSendfile is default 'On' in Apache 2.4 they switch it to default 'Off'. Struggled with this for a while. Thanks for posting this, helped a lot.

Comment: I don't know if it would appropriate to edit the answer with what I'm about to share, as the question is about windows, but as hinted by @99Sono be aware that if you the Apache server is on Linux or other non-Windows system containing a CIFS share that needs to be made available, it is probably best to use the enable EnableSendfile only for the CIFS mount.