# Apache 2.4 in Windows send incomplete files

Tags: windows-server-2012, apache-2.4

I have an Apache 2.4.10 in Windows 2012 that sends incomplete files. Similar to the issue reported in ([Apache 2.4 on Windows 2008 large file downloads are corrupt](https://serverfault.com/questions/470403/apache-2-4-on-windows-2008-large-file-downloads-are-corrupt)), there are no entries in the error logs related to the download. The access logs also show the size of the corrupted file downloaded and not the actual file size in the server.

However, unlike the previous posted question, EnableSendFile did not work on the configuration. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Use IIS?  Or, if you're married to Apache, run it on Linux?

Comment: We can't do either currently, though one choice if we cannot get this to work would be to downgrade to Apache 2.2.